# Jobs search returning unexpected results

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I have performed a job search for the string "director" with "Remote" as an option selected.

My query URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=director&r=true&ss=1&sort=p

I am not sure what this result is showing me. The first several results are for developer positions. The string "director" does not appear in the job description at all. The Experience level is one of "Mid-Level, Senior, Lead", not "Manager".

Examples of jobs that are appearing:

- [Backend Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/512049/backend-developer-growth-engineering-soundtrack-your-brand?so=p&pg=1&offset=1&q=director&r=true)
- [Frontend Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/512048/frontend-developer-growth-engineering-soundtrack-your-brand?so=p&pg=1&offset=2&q=director&r=true)
- [Senior Engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/512018/senior-software-engineer-elixir-andela?so=p&pg=1&offset=3&q=director&r=true)
- [Product Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/494615/engineering-project-manager-gridunity-inc?so=p&pg=1&offset=4&q=director&r=true) - If you squint at this one, I could see how this would fit as "Director" is generally a "Manager" and the experience level for this is "Manager"
- [Senior Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/494578/senior-software-developer-remote-income-discovery?so=p&pg=1&offset=5&q=director&r=true)
- [Senior Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/494558/senior-software-engineer-dentally?so=p&pg=1&offset=6&q=director&r=true)

Why are these appearing with the search string I've provided?